Books about analytical fluid dynamics
I am looking for literature about analytical fluid dynamics and by analytical I mean analytical mechanics (Lagrangian, Hamiltonian,...). On the general reference list I couldn't find that topic. Also under fluid dynamics reference list I think there is none.
Do you know any books at all about analytical fluid dynamics? I could only find J. C. Luke (1967). "A Variational Principle for a Fluid with a Free Surface" but that is a paper. I also found Analytical Fluid Dynamics 3rd Edition
by George Emanuel, but I think the title is missleading and it doesn't deal with analytical mechanics of fluid dynamics at all.
Are any books on the topic analytical fluid dynamics even written?

There are a few references in this question that you might want to look at
